# Chat isn't letting me move messages, and isn't showing an error either

Tags: bug, chat, error-message

I was trying to move [these messages](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9597380#9597380) to [this room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8924/blender-bin), and it wasn't working.

Finally, I checked the "Network" tab of the Chrome Dev tools, and it showed me that every time I tried to move the messages, I would get one of those `aspxerrorpath` messages (except that it would be in the Network tab, so it was never shown to me unless I looked for it)

I was unable to reproduce the error with another moved message (the cat says that you guys keep logs, so that shouldn't be an issue). I finally moved the messages to trashcan.

But shouldn't there be some visual indication of the error?

Comment: Where those messages audit messages (like room topic changed etc)?